# How to read in a certain csv file column (up and down) Python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have a cvs file with data looking like:

```
lastname firstname id
segre    alberto   14562
```

I want to just read in the column with the id numbers 
everything I try keeps giving me the line not the column of the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import operator

idgetter = operator.itemgetter(2)
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    infile.readline()
    ids = [idgetter(row) for row in csv.reader(infile)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
col = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file/')['id']
```

And if you want it as a list, simply `list(col)` will do the trick.